# RegEx to only match numbers at the beginning of the string?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
3d33sds
32d33sds
312d33sds
```

How can I extract the numbers at the beginning of the string? The string always starts with numbers but can contain some letters and numbers after first numbers.

Comment: Is this a single string, or a couple of examples of what the relevant string might be?

Comment: See [PHP Regex to get leading digits only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673873/php-regex-to-get-leading-digits-only), I think it should suffice for this case.

Comment: I'd like to match all numbers at the beginning of the string it can be one or more then stop where letters begin.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew your answers it what i was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This regex

```
(?m)^(\d+).*
```

finds all numbers at the beginning of each string. The numbers you need will be inside group 1. Here is an explanation of the regex parts:

- `(?m)` declares the regex to read multiline data.
- `^` declares the start of line.
- `\d` declares a digit.
- `\d+` declares that there should be at least 1 digit.
- `(\d+)` declares a group so that you could extract the numbers from input lines.
- `.` declares any character.
- `.*` declares that there may be any number of any characters, that means any line (even an empty one).